# How to have navigation transition like native iOS app using React PWA?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps

I would like to build a PWA app using `create-react-app`. Paying $99 dollar per year for my previous mobile app is too costly and I need more economic solution. Therefore I choose PWA as the substitution for my mobile app.

I've done some research about PWA. But I haven't found any answer yet regarding how to achieve same (or maybe mostly look-alike) navigation transition like native iOS app ? These things includes:

1. New screen should be pushed into the "stack" and have enter animation
2. Going back from another screen should maintain scroll position of previous screen.

Any library or approach I can use to achieve what I need ?

Comment: Take a look at this post: [Make your web app feel native](https://blog.etch.team/react-page-transitions-make-your-website-feel-native-bf2804b011dc)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sorry for late reply. I appreciate it, but I think I still need something more than that :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is highly sort after by a lot of new PWA developers. Although I don't have the exact answers, I can point you in the right direction.

**Use Ant-design or ant-mobile**

These two libraries have native app-like components that work out of the box.

ant design - https://ant.design/components/overview/
ant mobile - https://mobile.ant.design/components/button

You will find that there are a lot of components that are quite similar to what you will find in native apps.

I do prefer ant design to ant mobile as components in ant design are easier to customize.

In summary, you might have to build these native experiences by piecing together components from the aforementioned libraries

**Take advantage of existing PWAs**

Some existing PWAs have this functionality. I think you can look at their source codes to see how they are doing it.

An example of this is https://github.com/husker-dev/web-ios-app